# Fetch objects upon pagination, rather than beforehand? (Rails + Kaminari)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

So I have a search controller that returns a array of Object IDs (in this case 'Users').

Since the search results array can contain hundreds of IDs, I'd rather fetch the actual Objects themselves only when I need to send them to the view. In short, I want to use pagination to fetch the Objects themselves beforehand for each chunk of IDs (i.e. 1..10, 11..20, etc), rather than have the view logic fetch the Objects. I have no idea how to accomplish this.

**My controller code**

```
users = [1,3,456,23423,234,23...]
#somehow have the pagination get the Objects from DB for each page
@persons = Kaminari.paginate_array(users).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

**View**

```
- @persons.each do |person| #I WANT TO HAVE THE FULL WRITER OBJECT BY NOW
  = person.name             # instead of doing a 'User.find(person.id)' in the view
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put a page number parameter in the url.  Then if you want to display 10 per page and say the user clicks page three, subtract page number by one page (10) and add one giving you 21. this is your start for the database query. and limit to 10 results

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. You can just map or collect a new array based on the @persons array